# How to convert blender scripts bpy to python scripts py

Tags: python, scripting

I am new to Python and Blender and would like to know:

1. How to convert Blender scripts (bpy) to Python scripts (py)?
2. What is the difference between Blender scripts and Python scripts?

Comment: Hi and welcome! I did revert your edit because the context got lost for future visitors. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour. If you have another question, please [ask a new one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scripts written for Blender are Python scripts (`*.py`). The difference is that they may use [Blender's API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html) through `import bpy` which is not available to a regular Python interpreter out of the box. If the script is using anything from the `bpy` namespace it can't be executed outside of Blender, that is unless you build and install [Blender as a Python module](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule). In this case you get (limited) access to Blender's Python API to functionality that does not require a UI. As long as a Python script does not use Blender's API, then it can be executed by a regular Python interpreter without any modifications.

---

**How to convert Blender scripts to Python scripts?**

You don't. If it uses Blender's API you can either execute it in Blender or you have to install Blender as Python module for your Python interpreter.

**What is the difference between Blender scripts and Python scripts?**

The use of Blender's API is the difference. Other than that they are just regular Python scripts, the programming language is the same.